# Recent literature on the gaps of reals on $L$ or other inner models?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, textbook-recommendation, inner-model-theory

I'm doing my Bachelor's Thesis on Gödel's constructible universe $L$.

I'm interested in the gaps without new reals (sets of natural numbers) in the hierarchy, as presented in [Gaps in the constructible universe, Marek and Srebrny, 1973](https://zbmath.org/?q=Gaps%20in%20the%20constructible%20universe%2C%20Marek%20and%20Srebrny). Of course, the issue is deeply linked to the fine structure of $L$, as studied in [The fine structure of the constructible hierarchy, Jensen, 1971.](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0257.02035)

I'm searching for recent literature on these issues. Especially, since the gaps in $L$ itself seem to have been thoroughly studied long ago, my advisor has recommended I look for similar results for generalizations or extensions of $L$, such as $L(\mathbb{R})$ and its $\Sigma_1$-Gaps, or inner models of large cardinals, such as $L(U)$. I haven't found anything yet, other than Steel's [Scales in $L(\mathbb{R})$](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1159.03323), and I'd be very grateful for any information or advice you might have.

The standard text, [Constructibility](https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=ai%3Adevlin.keith-j) by Devlin, doesn't seem to touch upon gaps of this kind. Gap-$n$ morasses are studied, but from what I understood they're an unrelated concept. I'm also aware of modern developments of fine structure theory, such as hyperfine structure, but these seem again to touch only upon Gap-$n$ morasses.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Steel has a paper on gaps in $K(\mathbb R)$ and a few related papers in the reissued Cabal vol. I and a follow up in the JSL.

Comment: For posterity: the OP's thesis is now uploaded to the arXiv, "[The real numbers in inner models of set theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.10754)", also with a brief mention of the concept of higher-order gaps in [MO answer #424952](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424952).